# Write/Read AMD geode LX800 CPU EEPROM

Tags: embedded-linux, cpu-registers, eeprom, msr

I have read in AMD geode LX800 CPU datasheet (http://goo.gl/fUl5RM) that this CPU have in Security Block an internal EEPROM that can be used to store  user data.

I can read and write MSR registers using linux, but i dont now how to access eeprom addresses via MSR registers (is it possible?). I don't have any ideia how to do it, someone could help me?

Thanks in advance.